# Criar Nova Coluna em DataFrame com base em coluna com função def_Pandas

Tags: python, funções, pandas, visual-studio-code, dataframe

Gostaria de adicionar em um DataFrame os resultados que obtive depois de aplicar a seguinte função em duas colunas desse DataFrame:

> Colunas do DataFrame: "DATA", "VEÍCULO" e "Análise qualitativa das matérias"

> Desejo saber a quantidade de Análise qualitativa NEGATIVA, Análise POSITIVA e NEUTRA por VEÍCULO

> Colunas e Dados do Dataframe:

```
#Colunas e Dados do DataFrame:

DATA                               VEÍCULOS Análise qualitativa das matérias
0     01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA
1     01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                            NEUTRA
2     01/01/2023     ESPORTES E NOTÍCIAS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA
3     01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA
4     01/01/2023                BLOG DO PEDRO LUIS [MT]                         POSITIVA
...          ...                                    ...                              ...
1639  31/01/2023       TBO/TV BRASIL OESTE - CUIABÁ MT                            NEUTRA
1640  31/01/2023  BARRA EM FOCO - BARRA DO BUGRES - MT                            NEUTRA
1641  31/01/2023             DIÁRIO DIGITAL MT - CUIABÁ                           NEUTRA
1642  31/01/2023                     A FOLHA NEWS - MT                            NEUTRA
1643  31/01/2023                  J1 AGORA - MT ONLINE                            NEUTRA
```

> Eu quis agrupar a quantidade de dados da coluna 'VEÍCULOS' que na coluna 'Análise qualitativa de matérias' estavam como 'NEGATIVAS'. Mas,depois, precisava contá-las e atribuir o número de vezes em que cada VEÍCULO apareceu como NEGATIVO.Então, usei o bloco de função abaixo:

```
#Entrada:
def counter_(g, threshold=['NEGATIVA']):
    num= len(g[g == 'NEGATIVA'])
    return num
secom_df = (secom_df.groupby('VEÍCULOS')['Análise qualitativa das matérias'].apply(counter_))

#Saída:
    VEÍCULOS
360 FATOS - CUIABÁ - MT                                       2
360 NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                                        0
A BRONCA POPULAR [MT]                                         2
A FOLHA DO MÉDIO NORTE ONLINE - BARRA DO BUGRES - MT [MT]     0
A FOLHA MT - CUIABÁ MT                                        2
                                                             ..
ZAKI NEWS - CÁCERES - MT                                      0
ÁGUA BOA NEWS - MT                                            0
ÂNCORA NOTÍCIAS - MT                                          0
ÚLTIMA HORA MT - CUIABÁ - MT                                  9
ÚNICA NEWS - MT                                              89
```

> Por exemplo, após aplicar a função def acima, o VEÍCULO "ÚNICA NEWS-MT" teve 89 aparições como'NEGATIVAS'

> DESEJO adicionar essa coluna com função 'def', como uma NOVA COLUNA no DataFrame "secom_df" já existente. Já tentei transformar esse bloco 'def' em uma Nova Coluna denominada 'secom_df['ANÁLISE NEGATIVA']' a partir da atribuição dos resultados desse bloco a uma variável 'secom_df_jan', mas a Saída vem com valores 'NaN', como fazer?

```
#Entrada:
secom_df_jan = (secom_df.groupby('VEÍCULOS')['Análise qualitativa das matérias'].apply(counter_))
```

secom_df['ANÁLISE NEGATIVA'] = secom_df_jan

```
#Saída
    DATA                            VEÍCULOS Análise qualitativa das matérias  ANÁLISE NEGATIVA
0      01/01/2023              RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA               NaN
1      01/01/2023              RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                            NEUTRA               NaN
2      01/01/2023  ESPORTES E NOTÍCIAS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA               NaN
3      01/01/2023              RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA               NaN
4      01/01/2023             BLOG DO PEDRO LUIS [MT]                         POSITIVA               NaN
...           ...                                 ...                              ...               ...
42992  31/12/2023             FOLHAMAX - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA               NaN
42993  31/12/2023             LEIAGORA - CUIABÁ - MT                            NEUTRA               NaN
42994  31/12/2023          O DOCUMENTO - CUIABÁ - MT                          POSITIVA               NaN
42995  31/12/2023             FOLHAMAX - CUIABÁ - MT                            NEUTRA               NaN
42996  31/12/2023               RDM ON-LINE - MT [MT]                           NEUTRA               NaN
```

(Estou usando Windows 10, Visual StudioCode, Python 3.11.8 e Pandas)

> Se não fui clara, favor me informar, pois o Fórum ainda não me permite anexar a imagem.

Answer (score -2):

O problema é aqui

```
    secom_df['ANÁLISE NEGATIVA'] = secom_df_jan
```

Você está apenas inserindo a coluna, mas sem associar os valores de cada elemento da série secom_df_jan aos veículos do df secom_df. Como não há valores associados, ele imprimirá NaN, que é como o pandas representa valores numéricos ausentes

Use um map para preencher cada linha de ANÁLISE NEGATIVA com os valores da série secom_df_jan para cada veículo:

```
    secom_df['ANÁLISE NEGATIVA'] = secom_df['VEÍCULOS'].map(secom_df_jan)
```

Teste baseado no df que forneceu (substitui algumas análises por Negativa para conter todos os valores possíveis na entrada)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'DATA': ['01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023',
             '31/01/2023', '31/01/2023', '31/01/2023', '31/01/2023', '31/01/2023'],
    'VEÍCULOS': ['RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT', 'RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT', 'ESPORTES E NOTÍCIAS - CUIABÁ - MT', 
                 'RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT', 'BLOG DO PEDRO LUIS [MT]', 'TBO/TV BRASIL OESTE - CUIABÁ MT', 
                 'BARRA EM FOCO - BARRA DO BUGRES - MT', 'DIÁRIO DIGITAL MT - CUIABÁ', 
                 'A FOLHA NEWS - MT', 'J1 AGORA - MT ONLINE'],
    'Análise qualitativa das matérias': ['POSITIVA', 'NEUTRA', 'POSITIVA', 'NEGATIVA', 'POSITIVA',
                                          'NEUTRA', 'NEUTRA', 'NEGATIVA', 'NEUTRA', 'NEUTRA']
}


def counter_(g, threshold=['NEGATIVA']):
    num = len(g[g.isin(threshold)])
    return num

secom_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
secom_df_jan = secom_df.groupby('VEÍCULOS')['Análise qualitativa das matérias'].apply(counter_)
secom_df['ANÁLISE NEGATIVA'] = secom_df['VEÍCULOS'].map(secom_df_jan)
print(secom_df)
```

```
#Output:
         DATA                              VEÍCULOS Análise qualitativa das matérias  ANÁLISE NEGATIVA
0  01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                         POSITIVA                 1
1  01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                           NEUTRA                 1
2  01/01/2023     ESPORTES E NOTÍCIAS - CUIABÁ - MT                         POSITIVA                 0
3  01/01/2023                 RD NEWS - CUIABÁ - MT                         NEGATIVA                 1
4  01/01/2023               BLOG DO PEDRO LUIS [MT]                         POSITIVA                 0
5  31/01/2023       TBO/TV BRASIL OESTE - CUIABÁ MT                           NEUTRA                 0
6  31/01/2023  BARRA EM FOCO - BARRA DO BUGRES - MT                           NEUTRA                 0
7  31/01/2023            DIÁRIO DIGITAL MT - CUIABÁ                         NEGATIVA                 1
8  31/01/2023                     A FOLHA NEWS - MT                           NEUTRA                 0
9  31/01/2023                  J1 AGORA - MT ONLINE                           NEUTRA                 0
```

Veja mais sobre o uso de map aqui:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html

Aqui a documentação sobre dados ausentes (e são vários, o "N" depois de Na representa o tipo de dados que ele esperava, neste caso numérico ):
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#working-with-missing-data

Outra alternativa é você usa métodos de junção e mesclagem de dfs e séries do pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html
Eles podem lidar com isso, mas retornam um novo df e , pelo que solicitou, você deseja adicionar a coluna ao existente, o mantendo.

Comment: Olá Luigi, obrigada por responder...vou tentar essa função "map". Ressalto desde já que eu queria um Resultado diferente, eu queria era que cada "VEÍCULO" saísse  única vez e com a quantidade de vezes que eles tiveram as avaliações NEGATIVAS, não queria que os "VEÍCULOS"  se repetissem. Será que é possível fazer isso e ainda associar os valores da forma como mencionei, isto é, associar com as demais colunas de"Análise qualitativa das matérias" e a nova coluna "ANÁLISE NEGATIVA"? Acredito que se for acrescentar esse associação com a Coluna "Datas" não daria, certo?

Comment: O que dá pra fazer é criar um df de dados para cada veículo à secom_df_jan

`
def get_data(g, df):
    return df.loc[df['VEÍCULOS'] == g].reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['VEÍCULOS'])

secom_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
secom_df_jan = secom_df.groupby('VEÍCULOS')['Análise qualitativa das matérias'].apply(counter_).reset_index(name='ANÁLISE NEGATIVA')
secom_df_jan['Análise qualitativa das matérias'] = secom_df_jan.apply(lambda row: get_data(row['VEÍCULOS'], secom_df ), axis=1)

`
secom_df_jan terá linhas únicas de cada veículo, com os dados dele em Análise qualitativa das matérias